# how to use Hololens emulator in visual studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio-2019, hololens

I have followed all the steges in the link below, but I don't know how I get holographic to do the first HoloLens emulator project in visual studio 2019, any one kan tell me please.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/install-the-tools

Thank you